# Jquery Checkbox uncheck with if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't quite figure out why my code is not working here.

I have an `if` statements that checks if 1 or more check boxes have been checked, then if its true a function runs. The function allows a bar to slide down when the page scrolls to a certain height.

It works when I first visit the site after a refresh. i.e the bar is not visible, when I scroll, then when I check a box, it becomes visible.

However when I uncheck the box the bar is still visible!

How do I hide it, when the checkbox is unchecked?

I thought a line in the else statement like the below would work, but they don't ( I even tried to add an `else if`:

```
$(".userbar").hide(); //OR
$(".userbar").slideUp(); //OR
$(".userbar").off();
```

Here is my Code:

```
$(document).on('change', '#est', function (e){
    // Get number of checkboxes checked.
    var counter = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
    console.log("Checkboxs checked number: " + counter);
    e.preventDefault();
    if (counter >= 1 ) {
      $(window).scroll(function() {
          if ($(this).scrollTop() < 370)
          {
              $(".userbar").slideUp(100);
          }
          else
          {
              $(".userbar").slideDown(100);
          }
      });
    } else if (counter == 0 ){
            $(".userbar").hide();
          }
});
```

Comment: I've found adding `$(".userbar").css("height","0");` `$(".userbar").css("border-bottom","none");` Works. However I don't believe its the best solution!

Comment: Begginer at all this... I thought this was the handler... `$(document).on('change', '#est', function (e){` for the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time that `counter >= 1`, you bind a function to the `window` `"scroll"` event, and that function will decide if the bar will be visible or not. Even if later `counter` evaluates at zero, and you run the `.hide()`, the `scroll` handler you registered before will still be there and run again.

An easy way to fix this would be to add something like

```
else if (counter == 0 ){
    $(window).off("scroll");
    $(".userbar").hide();
}
```

Be aware that `.off("scroll")` will remove any handler for the "scroll" event. If you have others and you want to keep them, you might want to name your handler and remove it individually, like:

```
function myScrollHandler() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 370)
    {
        $(".userbar").slideUp(100);
    }
    else
    {
        $(".userbar").slideDown(100);
    }
}
// ...
$(window).scroll(myScrollHandler);
// ...
$(window).off("scroll", myScrollHandler);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! the else if works, but I am struggling to add the custom scroll handler function as I have other scroll handlers. Can you help me with is?